# Google Chrome developer tools: missing storage tab

Tags: google-chrome, local-storage, google-chrome-devtools

For unknown reasons, when I use Google chrome (version 9.0.597.84), the developer tools aren't showing the "Storage" tab (mentioned/illustrated, for example, at http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/developertools/part1/#toc-overview-storage and http://webdevlife.com/getting-started-with-localstorage-in-html5/), which I need to examine and modify localStorage. Any idea either what I would do to get this tab or what would be a workaround? I'm aware I can simply dump localStorage and I can write code to modify it, but this will probably be an ongoing concern in my work and I'd really like to have a proper tool.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is now under the resources tab within the "Storage" tree node item. I submitted a bug report for this:
http://code.google.com/p/html5rocks/issues/detail?id=421

Hope that helped!

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to use firefox or you can access local storage in application tab on google chrome